# How to programmatically add a website shortcut to a iOS devices home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Hi I'm developing a iOS app that needs the ability to add shortcuts to the home screen.
I've searched around abit but all the answers seem to be out of date, how would I go about this as I know it's possible because you can do it in Safari and the Shortcuts app?

Comment: Apple's apps can do things that other apps can't. Adding a shortcut to the Home Screen is one of those things.

Comment: @Paulw11 is there a api for interacting with the shortcuts app?